# Creating a photos model for my properties table

Tags: php, laravel

1) I have my Property model

```
public function images()
{
     return $this->hasMany(PropertyImages::class);
}
```

2) My table for PropertyImages model is as follows:

```
Schema::create('property_images', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->bigIncrements('id');
       $table->string('title')->nullable();
       $table->string('src');
       $table->string('mime_type')->nullable();
       $table->string('alt')->nullable();
       $table->text('description')->nullable();
       $table->integer('property_id');
       $table->timestamps();
});
```

3) When I have the code:

```
$properties = Property::all();
dd($properties->images());
```

Nothing seems to work.
I want it so each property has a variety of images I'm wondering why it is not recognizing the data. I receive the following error: BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::images does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call a object function in a `Collection`. To get the images you need to iterate over the `Collection`. Try this:

```
$properties = Property::all();
foreach ($properties as $property) {
    dd($property->images);
}
```

Or even try to get only one object at a time:

```
$property = Property::first();
dd($property->images);
```

Another detail you have to notice is that you usually not call a relation like a function, you call it like an attribute. So, do not call `$obj->images()` but `$obj->images`.

Comment: If a property has multiple images, is there a way to just "pluck" one of them? For example, I got my code up and running                 foreach ($property->images as $image)
                <div class="properties-img"><img src="{{ $image->src }}"></div>
                endforeach, but is there a way I can only grab 1 per property to display?

Comment: I found a way using slice().

Comment: You can achieve this calling the method and calling `first()` after it. Try this: `$property->images()->first();`.

Answer (score 1):

You can "pluck" the images out of the collection to get a collection of related images.

```php
$images = Property::all()->pluck('images');
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck

Comment: Is it possible to just pick one from the many images to display? Say property 1 has 3 images but I only want one of them show.

Comment: I found a way using the slice method.